# How to upload Facebook profile image from graph API to Firebase Storage in Flutter app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

So I am developing this chat app that uses Facebook login then uses the token to login Firebase Authentication.

The app uses Facebook profile picture as the user's profile. I read the Facebook profile pic from Facebook Graph API. The problem is that the URL for Facebook profile URL will be expired in certain a mount of time. I can't just store the Facebook Graph URL in Firebase Database along with the user message. So what I need to do is to store the profile image on Firebase Storage first then map its URL in the Firebase database.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

In firebase we have one storage option available where you can store media files (images, audio etc). You can get that image and store in thos storage and use that image for your use.